# UITableView or StackView

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, uistackview

I'm currently using storyboard in xcode to come up with the layout below.
The whole screen is a tableView with 2 different prototype cells. Depending on the data available, one of the 2 cells will be created.

For the second cell, what's the best way put the tableview with Label2 and img2? 
I tried putting it in a simple stack view with 1px line(a UIView) drawn across, but the line appears thinner or ticker depending on the device screen size.

A TableView solves the line problem, but it seems like a lot of work for such a simple layout. Specially when there is a tableView inside a tableView is involved.

Is stackview the way to go here? Maybe I'm missing something that causes the seperator lines to look different across devices? Or is another tableView more conventional way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Note: Often the lines appear thicker or thinner in the same screen. Like the first 2 lines will be alright, but the third one will be thicker.

Comment: Note 2: putting the lines at 2px height seems to be more uniform. But the ui looks bad with 2 px lines.

Answer (score 0):

I can maybe think of a solution using border in layer of views :

```
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

I don't really know what your stackView looks like but I think you could adapt this solution in your case :)

Comment: Yea I gave the line a constant height of 1 px. I even gave the cells a constant height of 30px, but that doesn't help either. I suspect the auto layout is trying to fill in any discrepancy in the cell content, but I'm not sure why a line with fixed 1px height would appear any different.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, a very rookie mistake. Turns out it's just the simulator. 
When I use it on an actual device, it's all fine. **In the simulator, remember to set the zoom to 100%.** (cmd+1/2/3) Otherwise thin lines like this appear very different.

As for the chosen method, I just went with stackview with UIView of 1px in between each cells. This is much easier to populate with data for such simple layout.